# WP-bakery Right click-save as is disabled. I want to enable it

Tags: javascript, wordpress, wpbakery

I use Wordpress as a CMS for my website. I'm Using the Sugarland Theme by Thomas Rodus (Which uses WP-Bakery as a page builder), unfortunately my support has run out and I JUST realized that right click-save as/downloading images from my website is disabled/inaccessible. This isn't great as it means any potential clients, agencies, etc, can't quickly save my images and store them for later viewing.

My knowledge is limited but I've managed to do some customizing myself throughout the years of using WP and hosting my website and whatnot. I can usually figure out what's wrong and fix it, but I can't find which element is causing the issue, if it's the PHP files (content-portfolio-ajax , content-portfolio-nav) for the AJAX overlay, or the Jquery files (jquery.fancybox.pack) as I can't see anything obvious suggesting something is disabled.

------ Content-portfolio-ajax:---------

```
<?php 
    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);
?>

<div id="project-title" class="centered">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">

            <?php 
                the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); 
                the_excerpt();
            ?>

            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="button"><?php esc_html_e('Details', 'sugarland'); ?></a>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="project-slider">

    <figure class="images">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail('full'); ?>
    </figure>

    <?php if(!empty($next_post)) : ?>
        <a class="ajax-prev" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($next_post->ID)); ?>"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if(!empty($prev_post)) : ?>
        <a class="ajax-next" href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($prev_post->ID)); ?>"></a>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

-------- or content-portfolio-nav: ---------

```
<?php
    global $post;

    $url[] = '';
    $url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');

    $prev_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', true);
    $next_post = get_adjacent_post(false, '', false);       

    $displays = get_option('ebor_cpt_display_options');
    $slug = ( $displays['portfolio_slug'] ) ? $displays['portfolio_slug'] : $slug = 'portfolio';
?>

<div class="padding-0 clearfix" data-ref="mixitup-container">

    <?php if(!empty($prev_post)) : ?>
        <div class="mix item clearfix col-sm-4 col-xs-12 home portfolio lifestyle" data-ref="mixitup-target">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($prev_post->ID)); ?>">
                <figure class="images"> 
                    <?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $prev_post->ID ), 'full'); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($src[0]); ?>" alt="<span><?php echo ebor_the_terms('portfolio_category', ', ', 'name'); ?></span><?php echo get_the_title($prev_post->ID); ?>" class="slip" /> 
                </figure>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="mix item clearfix col-sm-4 col-xs-12 home portfolio blank" data-ref="mixitup-target">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url('/') . $slug ); ?>">

            <figure class="images"> 
                <img src="<?php echo EBOR_THEME_DIRECTORY; ?>assets/images/blank.jpg" alt="Blank Image" /> 
            </figure>

            <div class="info-box-content">
                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="child">
                        <h5><i class="fa fa-th"></i> <?php esc_html_e('Overview', 'sugarland'); ?></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </a>
    </div>

    <?php if(!empty($next_post)) : ?>
        <div class="mix item clearfix col-sm-4 col-xs-12 home portfolio travel" data-ref="mixitup-target">
            <a href="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink($next_post->ID)); ?>">
                <figure class="images"> 
                    <?php $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id( $next_post->ID ), 'full'); ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo esc_url($src[0]); ?>" alt="<span><?php echo ebor_the_terms('portfolio_category', ', ', 'name'); ?></span><?php echo get_the_title($next_post->ID); ?>" class="slip" /> 
                </figure>
            </a>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

----Or this JS (jquery.fancybox.pack) (I didn't paste the entire thing because it's large and I'm not sure which bit would be relevant to the problem. ------

```
(function(C,z,f,r){var q=f(C),n=f(z),b=f.fancybox=function(){b.open.apply(this,arguments)},H=navigator.userAgent.match(/msie/i),w=null,s=z.createTouch!==r,t=function(a){return a&&a.hasOwnProperty&&a instanceof f},p=function(a){return a&&"string"===f.type(a)},F=function(a){return p(a)&&0<a.indexOf("%")},l=function(a,d){var e=parseInt(a,10)||0;d&&F(a)&&(e*=b.getViewport()[d]/100);return Math.ceil(e)},x=function(a,b){return l(a,b)+"px"};f.extend(b,{version:"2.1.4",defaults:{padding:0,margin:10,width:800,
height:600,minWidth:100,minHeight:100,maxWidth:9999,maxHeight:9999,autoSize:!0,autoHeight:!1,autoWidth:!1,autoResize:!0,autoCenter:!s,fitToView:!0,aspectRatio:!1,topRatio:0.5,leftRatio:0.5,scrolling:"auto",wrapCSS:"",arrows:!0,closeBtn:!0,closeClick:!1,nextClick:!1,mouseWheel:!0,autoPlay:!1,playSpeed:3E3,preload:3,modal:!1,loop:!0,ajax:{dataType:"html",headers:{"X-fancyBox":!0}},iframe:{scrolling:"auto",preload:!0},swf:{wmode:"transparent",allowfullscreen:"true",allowscriptaccess:"always"},keys:{next:{13:"left",
34:"up",39:"left",40:"up"},prev:{8:"right",33:"down",37:"right",38:"down"},close:[27],play:[32],toggle:[70]},direction:{next:"left",prev:"right"},scrollOutside:!0,index:0,type:null,href:null,content:null,title:null,tpl:{wrap:'<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1"><div class="fancybox-skin"><div class="fancybox-outer"><div class="fancybox-inner"></div></div></div></div>',image:'<img class="fancybox-image" src="{href}" alt="" />',iframe:'<iframe id="fancybox-frame{rnd}" name="fancybox-frame{rnd}" class="fancybox-iframe" frameborder="0" vspace="0" hspace="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen'+
```

Sorry, I know this is probably a long shot. And I'm sorry about my obvious cluelessness around this, but I've spent the last few weeks trying to figure out what the problem is. Thank you so much to anyone who looks over this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to disable right click, but a common way is

`document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());`

If you're going to disable the disabling, you'll need to find the reference to `contextmenu` or `onContextMenu` or something similar.

The snippets you included didn't have this in it, so it's probably somewhere else in the theme or plugin folder.

Without more code, I can't help much, but good luck trying to find it yourself! Let us know if there's more info you can give.

Comment: Thank you! I'll go through my files and see if I can find something referencing that. thank you for your help :D